# Gradle - Exclude file from being packaged with jar

Tags: java, gradle, properties-file

I want to **exclude** `AMAuthN.properties` from the built jar. This file keeps showing up in the root folder of the compiled jar. The file is located at `AMAuthN\src\main\resources\AMAuthN.properties` relative to the project folder root. Thanks!

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

version = '1.0'
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6

test {
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}

// Create a single Jar with all dependencies
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',  
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': 'com.axa.openam'
    }

    baseName = project.name

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) 
        }
    }
}

// Get dependencies from Maven central repository
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Project dependencies
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can try something like this, which i know works on my end. In your `build.gradle` under the `JAR` definition add your **exclude**. Ex:

```
jar {     
   exclude('your thing')     
}
```

Comment: for excluding more than one thing use: `jar { exclude('thing1', 'thing2')}`

Comment: what path we should add?

Comment: Is there no way to put properties files in a separate directory from src and then instruct Gradle to use an updated classpath which includes the property files when running tests?

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work. I first tried with no path and then with a fully-qualified path, but the file I'm trying to exclude still appears in the JAR file.

Comment: As some people are asking what exactly to exclude, `jar {
    exclude('com/example/abcd.class');
}
` works for me.

Comment: Me too! Have you found the solution? @GregBrown

Comment: @arthurdai - I don't think I did. As I recall I was able to resolve my issue another way.