# Exclude class from jar with gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, jar

I've seen these:

[Gradle - Exclude file from being packaged with jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663838/gradle-exclude-file-from-being-packaged-with-jar)

[Exclude one class file in gradle Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913406/exclude-one-class-file-in-gradle-android-studio)

and am wondering what path or name I should use with `exclude`.  This is in a gradle.kts file:

```
group = "kaldrn.core"

jar {
    exclude("kaldrn/CliKt.class")
}
```

That's my best guess, since it's the filepath in the jar.  I've also tried using the source file, which doesn't work. I've tried using just basenames without path, no luck.  The significance of the `group` declaration in this context, if any, is lost on me (I was never a big java user pre kotlin).

The class is defined in `cli.kt`, in `package kaldrn`.

How do I determine what to use here?

---

Perhaps ironically **the path above turns out to be the correct one** -- see my comments on the accepted answer about a very nasty caveat that affects gradle and `jar { exclude ...}`, at least for version 6.7.

Comment: What's the package of your class and its name? Is it just `kaldrn.Cli` or something else?

Comment: It would be `kaldrn.cli`, which compiled gets javafied into `CliKt.class`.  I've edited that and some related bits in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exclude path should contain the full path to the target file from the source route (eg, from `main`).

In your case:

```
jar {
    exclude("kaldrn/cli/CliKt.class")
}
```

If you are unsure in the path, look for your file under `build/classes/kotlin/main`

Comment: This works, but I see now why I didn't hit upon it before: Once that has worked, if I change the `exclude` *it's ignored in favour of the previous version*, even using `./gradlew clean; ./gradlew --no-build-cache jar`.  I had to delete most of the contents of `~/.gradle/cache` (as in, the user's home cache), something I've never done before -- although perhaps I should do, because I am sure now what happened earlier was it was just employing the first path I tried (**the correct one turns out to be the one in the question here**, ie., my "best guess").

Comment: ....I can reproduce this very consistently so probably grounds for a bug report.  That can't be the right behaviour?  Have you noticed anything like this or is there an obvious point I've missed?  I'm sort of horrified to consider what else this applies to and all the previous times I've been unable to get something simple that should work to work and it just doesn't. ARGH!  It is such a hot mess of a tool. :/

Comment: Do you have this code in `buildSrc/build.gradle`, by chance?

Comment: Yes, and deleting all that stuff (everything but the `6.7` directory) also works (instead of the stuff in the home cache).  Dunno if this is because I am using the intelliJ interface and the `.gradlew` it created interchangeably.

Comment: `buildSrc` is for plugins, so Gradle won't rebuild it unless specifically told so:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, and was a bit flustered. I have no literal `buildSrc` directory.  I thought by that you meant "the top level of the project" -- plus a bit of unreading `build`, I was referring to the top `.gradle` directory.